# file_put_contents on mkdir fails to open stream: permission denied

Tags: php, php-5.6

I'm trying to upload a image from the app I developed. I keep getting this error `failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Here is my code on PHP 5.6

```
$target_dir = '../../uploads/temp/'.$username.'/'.$acad_year.'/'.$semester;

        if (!is_dir($target_dir))
        {
            mkdir($target_dir, 777, TRUE);
        }

        file_put_contents($target_dir, base64_decode($_POST['image']));
```

Here is the error

```
file_put_contents(../../uploads/temp/asdasda/2019-2020/2nd): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\sfas\android_app\v1\UploadPicture.php</b>
```

I have done some research but nothing works.

Comment: Yes it is created. What can I do?

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly recommend you work on upgrading your application to a newer version of PHP; [the last official security fix for PHP 5.6](https://www.php.net/releases/#5.6.40) was nearly two years ago.

Comment: Shouldn't your file_put_contents be to a file within the `$target_dir` and not to the directory itself.

Comment: Oh. I 'am running on windows. So is this not possible for windows or is there a way around this?

Comment: @JohnMicko Ignore my previous comments, and see Nigel Ren's comment. You're trying to write data to a directory, not a file inside the directory.

Comment: Now it's working! Thank you both for your answers. You saved me. I'll try to pay more attention. God bless you guys